# P4V Won't Sync All Files/Folders

Tags: perforce, p4v

I am rather new to P4V, so I apologize if this is obvious, but I cannot figure out a solution to my problem.

I have a depot that I have connected to just fine, and navigate to the folder that I wish to get the latest revision of.  Great, no problem so far.

I right-click the folder, and select "Get Lastest Revision".  Except, it doesn't.  It only grabs some of the files from the folder.

Fine.  So I right-click the folder, select "Get Revision", have the radio selected for "Get Latest Revision", and check the box for "Force Operation".  Nothing, same behavior, missing the same files.
Tried starting P4V in admin mode.  Same behavior.

A coworker suggests I go into the workspace and manually exclude and then include the missing folders/files.  Same behavior.  Also suggests I try reverting to the initial commit of the missing folders/files, and then updating to the newest.  Same behavior, I'm only able to get the same files every time.

Okay, so time for a more extreme solution.  I restart, and use p4 sync ...#none in a command prompt to remove everything.  Somehow several dozen files throw the warning that they're in use even though I've just rebooted.  I don't know how this is possible, so I navigate to the folder via the File Explorer and delete them all manually.  I right-click the folder, and select "Get Latest Revision"... and nothing.

This is... frustrating.  This should be pretty simple - I just want the entire contents of a single folder, no frills.  What's even more confusing is that I had these files before, and when I did a "Get Latest Revision" they were deleted.  Coworkers are able to download all of the files in that folder with no problems - it's just a problem for me.  Which implies that there's an option/setting I have that's messing with things.  However, considering I just installed P4V for the first time, I know I haven't messed around with any of the settings, and don't know which ones to change to make this work.

Thanks for reading, and thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The fact that files show up as in use sounds key to me. Might there be an anti-virus scanner reading them? Also try out Process Explorer from Microsoft sysinternals to look for processes that have files in your workspace open.

Comment: I thought of that, and nothing.  I was able to manually delete the files with no "in use" warning either - just P4V thinks they're in use, for some reason.

Comment: Also, for those reading, an awful, but functional, work-around is to make a new workspace.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what type of files you are working with?  Do the files run/get tested from your local workspace?  Have you verified that the troublesome files are still present/the same in the depot?  The shotgun approach Junior mentioned (create a new workspace) will probably fix anything that is wrong, and unless your depot is massive, workspaces are created pretty quickly...of course if there is a corresponding eclipse workspace (or some other IDE) it may well be worth trouble shooting.  Let us know.

Comment: So like I said, it making a new workspace fixed the issue.  The problem was that I was downloading files from a shelveset.  In order to force them to re-download, I had to revert them, remove them, then re-download, then re-download from the shelfset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p4 sync and force sync fails only for the files that have been opened in the workspace. In case you want to sync such files, shelve and revert them to maintain a copy or just revert them and then try to force sync again! I have faced this problem several times and this always solved my problem!

Comment: This actually was another fix that I discovered later.